# python sort element in json

Tags: json, python-3.x

I'm using Firebase and got a sample JSON, the first element of each row is generated by firebase:

```
{
  "MyTestData" : {
    "-MU7wHvQcPHaD92TBkox" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:04\", \"efficiency\": 61}",
    "-MU7wIAFTFfbnx_Y0JNo" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:05\", \"efficiency\": 34}",
    "-MU7wIQ0L420rJDPwsjh" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:06\", \"efficiency\": 79}",
    "-MU7wIeTeJYTyq3fRFv-" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:07\", \"efficiency\": 76}",
    "-MU7wItnrzEHLIi5sjP3" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:08\", \"efficiency\": 63}",
    "-MU7wJ8fmHytV4uHjc0B" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:09\", \"efficiency\": 71}",
    "-MU7wLt2Esdld_xngP3e" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:20\", \"efficiency\": 42}",
    "-MU7wM7hpZRxat4ZB9Rn" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:21\", \"efficiency\": 43}",
    "-MU7wMMld85ixbm7AffD" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:22\", \"efficiency\": 62}"
  }
}
```

how can I use python to extract all "date" element?

and how can I calculate the "efficiency" of each date? like 2021-02-21 is (61+34+79)/3

thank you very much!

Comment: What you posted is a syntax error (no starting {).  The data itself is an object and each value is a string.  You could convert each value to a json object, or you could use regex to extract the data from the string.

Comment: sorry I have edited the question, the date is stored in json format and i didnot copy the whole thing

Comment: Does each of the keys in MyTestData still have the value of string, or is that supposed to be a json?

Comment: actually the data is all string and saved in json format by me, now I have exported it but don't know  how to sort them, because for each row the first element is generated by firebase and I don't need it.

Answer (score 1):

Your data no longer match the problem description (there is no 2021-02-21), but I think this is what you are trying to do.

```
import json
  
data = {
  "MyTestData" : {
    "-MU7wHvQcPHaD92TBkox" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:04\", \"efficiency\": 61}",
    "-MU7wIAFTFfbnx_Y0JNo" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:05\", \"efficiency\": 34}",
    "-MU7wIQ0L420rJDPwsjh" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:06\", \"efficiency\": 79}",
    "-MU7wIeTeJYTyq3fRFv-" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:07\", \"efficiency\": 76}",
    "-MU7wItnrzEHLIi5sjP3" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:08\", \"efficiency\": 63}",
    "-MU7wJ8fmHytV4uHjc0B" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:09\", \"efficiency\": 71}",
    "-MU7wLt2Esdld_xngP3e" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:20\", \"efficiency\": 42}",
    "-MU7wM7hpZRxat4ZB9Rn" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:21\", \"efficiency\": 43}",
    "-MU7wMMld85ixbm7AffD" : "{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:22\", \"efficiency\": 62}"
  }
}

d = {}
for s in data['MyTestData'].values():
   j = json.loads(s)
   if j['date'] not in d:
       d[j['date']] = []
   d[j['date']].append(j['efficiency'])
  
for k, v in d.items():
    print(k, sum(v) / len(v))
```

Which would give you this result:

```
(u'2021-02-22', 59)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer perfectly solved my question

Answer (score 0):

Added a new date value, given solution please check

```
import json
data = {
   "MyTestData":{
      "-MU7wHvQcPHaD92TBkox":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:04\", \"efficiency\": 61}",
      "-MU7wIAFTFfbnx_Y0JNo":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:05\", \"efficiency\": 34}",
      "-MU7wIQ0L420rJDPwsjh":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:06\", \"efficiency\": 79}",
      "-MU7wIeTeJYTyq3fRFv-":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:07\", \"efficiency\": 76}",
      "-MU7wItnrzEHLIi5sjP3":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:08\", \"efficiency\": 63}",
      "-MU7wJ8fmHytV4uHjc0B":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:09\", \"efficiency\": 71}",
      "-MU7wLt2Esdld_xngP3e":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:20\", \"efficiency\": 42}",
      "-MU7wM7hpZRxat4ZB9Rn":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:21\", \"efficiency\": 43}",
      "-MU7wMMld85ixbm7AffD":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-22\", \"time\": \"16:53:22\", \"efficiency\": 62}",
      "-MU7wMMld85ixbm7AffD":"{\"date\": \"2021-02-21\", \"time\": \"16:53:22\", \"efficiency\": 25}"
   }
}

def efficiency_cal(k,v):
    return {
        k: sum(v)/len(v)
    }

efficiency_dict = {}
for x in data['MyTestData'].values():
    y = json.loads(x)
    date = y['date']
    efficiency = y['efficiency']
    try:
        //To maintain data based on dates
        efficiency_dict[date] += [efficiency]
    except KeyError as e:
        efficiency_dict[date] = [efficiency]
res = list(map(efficiency_cal,efficiency_dict.keys(),efficiency_dict.values()))
print(res)
```

```
[{'2021-02-22': 58.625}, {'2021-02-21': 25.0}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer perfectly solved my question

Comment: @zzz please, like it if its useful. click on the answer is useful.

Comment: I have click that. Can you please explain what does this mean:except KeyError as e:
        efficiency_dict[date] = [efficiency]

Comment: here I m adding a value into dictionary, if we have a new value it will give an exception that the key is not there in "efficiency_dict", Hence I m added that value. we can use if condition also but this way is more faster then conditions.